# How to overcome "Cannot find method addLabel(string)" in Gmail App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

The below App Script fetches the first message of the first Gmail Inbox thread and checks the "From:" header against a regular expression.

Based on the outcome, we want to use [addLabel()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addLabel(GmailLabel)) to set a Gmail label.

It performs the fetch and test fine, but fails when attempting to set the label - `Cannot find method addLabel(string). (line 15, file "Code")`

```
function myFunction() {
 
  // Get first thread in Inbox.
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  // Get the first message in the thread.
  var message = thread.getMessages()[0];
  // Get a message header
  var headerstring = message.getHeader("From");
  
  // Check header for "rob" test string, apply label
  if ( headerstring.match(/rob/g) ) {
    thread.addLabel("MyLabel");
    Logger.log("Matched rob");
  } else {
    thread.addLabel("AnotherLabel"); // failing, not class scope?
    Logger.log("No match");
  }
  
  
}
```

It feels like the existence of `addLabel` within the `if` clause has robbed it of the application of GmailApp, since I have had `addLabel` functioning outside of one - am I right? This is my first script.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: As the error states, There is no method `addLabel(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The issue is that [addLabel(label)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addLabel(GmailLabel)) **does not** accept a `string` but an object of type `GmailLabel`.

If the labels are already created by you, you need to use [getUserLabelByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getuserlabelbynamename) where you can pass the label `name` as `string`, get a `GmailLabel` object back and finally pass it to `addLabel(label)`.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
 
  // Get first thread in Inbox.
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  // Get the first message in the thread.
  var message = thread.getMessages()[0];
  // Get a message header
  var headerstring = message.getHeader("From");
  
  // Check header for "rob" test string, apply label
  if ( headerstring.match(/rob/g) ) {   
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
    thread.addLabel(label);
    Logger.log("Matched rob");
  } else {
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("AnotherLabel");
    thread.addLabel(label);    
    Logger.log("No match");
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank-you for explaining. I need to get the label first.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/robertandrews/dc7d7a826deb564bff33e8d9b165ed4a